# REST API to /interaction/v1/events fails 403

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, error-messages

Im trying to trigger an API event for a journey.

I got my endpoint, my auth token, but when im using this to hit `/interaction/v1/events`, im getting this error 403.

```
{"documentation":"https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/403","errorcode":0,"message":"Not Authorized"}
```

I have no idea if its some permissions, the app are missing or where the error could be.

```
    $postData = array(
    'ContactKey' => '66706599', /*should this just be 1 contact key?*/
    'EventDefinitionKey'=>'APIEvent-bb0ebe04-f413-45cf-864b-123456'
    );

    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/events",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($postData),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "content-type: application/json",
        "Authorization: Bearer" .$token
      )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be the space between Bearer and token?

Use `"Authorization: Bearer " .$token` instead and try again.

Comment: Well spottet... that worked!